# Display only one success message when using nested inserts

Tags: jquery, ajax

There's a product insert form with multiple tabs like specs,prices(each one has a table in database)

The user can insert data to main tab alone or a combination of tabs that include main tab. The insert operation will fill all tables in one go (nested ajax) 
The problem is since each success callback got a message-box, numerous success messages will be shown

Whats the best way to prevent this? (Preferably not checking inputs in tabs markup )

```
 $('#ContentForm').ajaxForm({

            url: "/ContentManagement/ContentAdmin/InsertContent",
            type: "POST",
            complete: function (data) {

                $('#ContentListDiv').html(data.responseText);
                if (data.responseText.indexOf("successful!") >= 0) {
                    clearForm();
                }
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#ContentId").val(response);
                if ($("#PriceValue").val() == 0 || $("#PriceValue").val() == "") {

                        clearForm();

                } else {
                    $('#PriceForm').ajaxForm({

                        url: "/ContentManagement/Price/AddPrice",
                        type: "POST",
                        complete: function (data) {
                            if (data.responseText.startsWith("showError")) {

                            }
                            else {
                                $('#PriceListDiv').html(data.responseText);
                            }
                        },
                        success:function (errorText) {
                          alert("successful")
                    });
                    $('#PriceForm').submit();


                }
                var tableData = [];
                $("[id^='row-']").each(function () {
                    tableData.push({
                        attributeId: parseInt(this.id.split('-')[1]),
                        value: $(this).val()
                    });
                });

                if ($("#attributeDetailDiv").find('input').length !== 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("SaveContentAttributes","AttributeAdmin")",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ contentId: response, tableData: tableData }),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success:function () {
                       alert("successful")

                        }
                    }); 
                }



            }
```

Comment: Add ajax call in a nested manner and fire the success message only inside the inner ajax call.. Need to clarify more .Please reply

Comment: Yes I can do that since I don't show any error(error and success won't be displayed together if any outer inserts fail )